# Databricks Notebook Scala Spark Connect to MongoDB Could not initialize class com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig$

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, apache-spark, databricks

I'm using a Databricks Scala notebook with Spark to connect to MongoDB and I'm trying to understand why I'm getting this error when I try to connect to my MongoDB cluster. I simply want to able to read my from database but I'm not sure why this error keeps coming up.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig$
```

My code where I'm attempting to read from MongoDB is shown here.

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.{ParamGridBuilder, TrainValidationSplit}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark
import com.mongodb.spark.config.{ReadConfig, WriteConfig}
import com.mongodb.spark._
import com.mongodb.spark.config._

val data = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("database", "sample_airbnb").option("collection", "listingsAndReviews").load()
data.show()
```

I've also installed the following libraries in my notebook library

```
org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:2.4.0
mongodb_driver_3_12_3_javadoc.jar
mongodb_driver_3_12_3_javadoc.jar
bson_3_12_3_javadoc.jar
```

These are the uri used for the spark config

```
spark.mongodb.input.uri mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0-ofrzm.azure.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
spark.mongodb.output.uri mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0-ofrzm.azure.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled true
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

## I have same connection problem on dataproc using pyspark

### my solution:

Install these jars

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb.spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.4.0
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/bson/
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/
```

Pyspark:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder\
                    .master('local')\
                    .config('spark.mongodb.input.uri', 'mongodb://{ Host }:{ Port }/{ DB }.{ Collection }')\
                    .config('spark.mongodb.output.uri', 'mongodb://{ Host }:{ Port }/{ DB }.{ Collection }')\
                    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.4.0')\
                    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read\
          .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")\
          .option("database",{ DB })\
          .option("collection", { Collection })\
          .load()
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be different issues related to this:

- You're using connector compiled with Scala 2.12 on Databricks runtime that uses Scala 2.11 - this is most probable issue, as DBR 7.0 that uses Scala 2.12 was released almost 2 months later.  The rule of thumb - for DBR < 7.0, use artifact 2.4.x with `_2.11` in name, for DBR >= 7.0, use `_2.12` and version 3.0.0 of that library
- You don't have all dependencies downloaded.  Connector depends on many other libraries that need to be available.  It's better to specify library as Maven coordinates: `org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.4.0` - this will pull all necessary dependencies

Comment: I am adding this connector as a maven coordinates , still   I am facing this issue

Comment: what coordinates & what DBR version

Comment: well this issue is resolved I guess , what  I face now is different.
 Atlas cluster version is 4.x , and I see  following error in Atlas logs 

" Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: The server is configured to only allow SSL connections. Ending connection from 1xx.xx.xx.1xx:1xxx (IP of my databricks cluster) . "

Not sure if we need to set some  conf in spark to enable this TLS / ssl handshake

Comment: it's better to ask it as a separate question